# Possibility of adding html, css, js, ... to Go server?

Tags: javascript, html, css, go, server

I am having trouble getting files such as index.html, main.js, style.css and more on my server made in Go.
My html file works fine with javascript and css on my local file but I can not make it work on a server.

I already tried making this in my code, but it only starts html file and javascript, css, jquer, font are listed in console like the page was not found (404 Page not found).

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
r.HandleFunc("/events", eventHandler) //Ignore this
r.NotFoundHandler = http.HandlerFunc(notFound) //This is just a custom 404.

// Create and start HTTP server.
s := &http.Server{
    Handler: r,
    Addr:    config.Address,
}
```

My question is:

Is there any possibility to do this without Node.js. Is there any option that will display all my javascript files and css in the html. I really would not like to get this things complicated with Node.

**Note**

My codes for html, css, javascript all work. My server also works, the only thing needed now is adding the files to the server.

[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9TnUF.png)
 [This is what I should get on server.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/782Fu.png)

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body id='body'>
    <div class="app-body">
        <div id='left' class="left">
            <div class='conferenceRoom'>Conference room
                <h1 class="roomName">crane
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="status">
                <h1 id="free_busy" class="free_busy"></h1>
                <h1 id="duration" class="duration"></h1>

            </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <div class="date" id="date"></div>
            <div id='eventList' class="eventList"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
```

index.html
This are my files in a directory called Website. Server is started by:

```
        go run *.go -c config.toml
```

This is ran from the website folder. [And this is what the files look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aCi3.png)

Comment: so you're saying all of the other files (eg main.js, style.css) are in the same folder as index.html, but you can only get index.html?

Comment: Check the browser console's network tab, you'll probably see 404s for the assets, which is possibly caused by the incompatibility of the server's folder structure and the html files asset paths.

Comment: @dylan-myers yes all the files are in the same directory. But somehow it will display 404 Page not found in their console.

Comment: @mkopriva by that you mean that files pathed in the index.html are wrong?

Comment: @DavidB Yes, that is what I mean. Compare one of the urls of those requests that caused the 404 to the actual location of the file on the server.

Comment: @DavidB can you share us the index.html file, specifically the line where you include your main.js? Also can you share the URL where you can access the index.html file? (It doesn't have to be public we just need to see how you access the file)

Comment: @mkopriva Yes the url shows localhost:12112/main.js in the case of error. It displays 404. But do I need to create a new path for this certain file so it will display it on server.

Comment: @DavidB I doubt your server's public facing url is localhost:12112, or is it? Or is that a subfolder of the ./static/ folder on your server?

Comment: @mkopriva the server is not public. I start it using terminal. However it should work just as a public one no? I changed the url name with toml file.

Comment: @dylan-myers I edited the question and now you can see the html code. I access the by localhost:12112. It is a local server which I created.

Comment: @DavidB do any of the requests work? eg jquery.js. And all the files are in /static, including index.html?

Comment: @dylan-myers none of the requests work. jquery.js and main.js get overwritten my 404, therefore throws an error in console that there is a syntax error. And yes all the files are in static.

Comment: @DavidB this is very simple to do in Go, local or public, doesn't matter. There is no need for including Node. Please add to the question your project's folder structure, on the server, so we can see where the index file and the asset files live. Also you are using a relative path in your Go code, in that case make sure you start the go binary from the correct location in you server so that the program's cwd is what you assume it to be.

Comment: can you show us your folder structure? @DavidB

Comment: @mkopriva you can check all the files now. All files which should be running in index.html are in the directory called static.

Comment: @MichaelHampton all the files are in the same folder. I edited the post if you'd like to see the full content of the directory I am working in.

Comment: @DavidB silly question, but does localhost:12112/static/main.css work?

Comment: @DavidB try this [gist](https://gist.github.com/mkopriva/9a94487639b861df8b6c1217bdc91733), as you can see from the screen.png, both css and js are loaded just fine (this was executed on my local). Try creating this simplified version of your project on your server and see if it works, if it doesn't then I don't know how else to help; if it does work then try to isolate the cause of the issue by gradually changing the simplified version to the full version.

Comment: Are you using gorilla mux? If so that might be the issue. You should give a working example with imports.

Comment: @KennyGrant I am working with mux yes.

Comment: @dylan-myers localhost:12112/static/main.css throws out a 404.

Comment: @mkopriva Yes this is working, but let us say I now have two different servers and one of them displays data in a json file, and second one displays the html which pulls the data. Now there is a problem with func main(){} since there cannot be two different. Do you have any idea how to resolve this? And btw your code works like a charm, javascript and all, thank you very muhc. Mux was a problem I see.

Comment: @DavidB `main()` is not a problem, you can start one server inside a goroutine so that it doesn't block the other server from being started. Also you can have one server serve both, json and html+assets, this can be done by either routing or by using http headers and query parameters to tell the server what kind of data the client is requesting, and there might be other options. FWIW in my opinion routing is the cleaner option.

Comment: @mkopriva Currently I am on a project on where I need to create a server that displays the events which are booked on a completely different server.  I am using one test server with same json but the problem is that func main can not be used more than one time. However other things work. This is just a new problem that showed up after I have resolved this one.

Comment: @DavidB I don't think you have a "problem" but maybe I'm misunderstanding something... anyways `main` is the entrypoint for your program, having more than one entrypoints for a single program makes no sense, and this is not Go specific, the few other languages I know behave the same. If you need to share code between two programs, then create a non-main package and have the two programs import it. If you need two programs to communicate with each other, say over http, e.g. server A retrieves json from server B, then that's also doable, just use the `net/http.Client` type to send the requests.

Comment: @mkopriva Well I solved the so called "problem". The servers were in the same folder therefore func main got rewritten time and time again. So all I did was move one server to the other directory, because it was only a test server for the one which is actually going to be used and then started the servers from 2 different terminals. Thank you again for all of your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to feed a `http.FileServer` to Gorilla mux's `route.Handle` function. This handles a single URL, so it's only valid for the given URL, `/`.

What you want for serving static files is a `route.PathPrefix()`. This serves any URL path which *begins with* the given string, while `route.Handle()` serves only a path which matches the string exactly.

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "net/http"

    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
)

func main() {
    r := mux.NewRouter()
    r.PathPrefix("/").Handler(http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))

    // Create and start HTTP server.
    s := &http.Server{
        Handler: r,
        Addr:    ":8009",
    }

    log.Fatalln(s.ListenAndServe())
}
```

Comment: It does work differently than before, but still punches errors for each file in the static folder now. Most of them say it is a MIME type (text/plain)

Comment: Sorry, me again, does replacing `mux.NewRouter` with a custom router which uses http.FileServer (like this: https://golangcode.com/serve-static-assets-using-the-mux-router/) help?

Comment: @dylan-myers I have completely discarded mux from my code now and tried the normal server create approach. It works fine now.

Comment: @DavidB fair enough. This answer from Michael is probably a good answer for your question though, I'd accept it for anyone else with the same issue :)

Comment: @DavidB This minimal example works exactly as is. It's intended to demonstrate the concept while being `go run`able. If you had trouble adapting it to your existing code, you might ask a new question about that.